# Crossfire with HD 5850 and other 5xxx series card

Tags: graphics-card, crossfire

I am not too sure about the crossfire combinations. 
I have a HD 5850, do I have to use another 5850 to crossfire or can I use any card from the 5xxx family?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your HD 5850, you can crossfire with: 5970, 5870, 5850, and 5830 only

Check out this [AMD page on crossfire](http://sites.amd.com/us/game/technology/Pages/crossfirex.aspx). There's a [chart](http://sites.amd.com/PublishingImages/Public/Graphic_Illustrations/WebBannerJPEG/AMD_CrossfireX_Chart_1618W.jpg) on the bottom